# Org - How set up a main task with sub duplicate tasks in a numerical splited task

Tags: org-mode

Something like this:

```
* TODO Go for a walk [0/2]
** TODO Walk for 30 minutes
** TODO Walk for 30 minutes
```

Would become something like this:

```
* TODO Walk for 1 hour {0/2}
```

And then, the state cycle would be:

```
-> TODO {0/2} -> TODO {0/1} -> ... -> DONE {2/2} -> TODO {0/2} -> ...
```

Comment: [I was not the person who down-voted without leaving constructive criticism in the form of a comment.]  There is no built-in support (that I am aware of) to perform calculations and text modifications incorporating said calculations when using the org-cycle functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So long as all the tasks in one file have the same number of sub-tasks, then you can [customize the TODO keywords](http://orgmode.org/manual/Per_002dfile-keywords.html), like this:

```
#+SEQ_TODO: TODO:{0/2} TODO:{1/2} | DONE:{2/2}

* TODO:{0/2} Go for a walk
```

That should produce the state cycle you want.

After editing the `SEQ_TODO` keywords, you need to type `C-c C-c` on that line so that org will recognize the change.  Note that you can't use a normal space in a TODO keyword if you set it this way, although you could if you [set it programmatically](http://orgmode.org/manual/Workflow-states.html#Workflow-states), or you could use a unicode non-breaking space (e.g., type `C-x 8 <return> non br sp`).